# Opentok sending signal ios

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods, opentok

I got a problem with OpenTok, I got a session of OTSession and I want to call the method signalWithType so I can send a chat message.

In the start I have

```
var session : OTSession?
```

And then in my method where I want to send chat message from textField I get the error 'Could not find memember 'signalWithType'

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    let message = sendMessageField.text
    sendMessageField.text = ""
    var type = ""
    var maybeError : OTError?

    session?.signalWithType(type, string: message, connection: nil, error: maybeError)

    if let error = maybeError {
        println(error)
    } else {
        println("besked blev sendt")
    }
    return false
}
```

I can't find out why it says it as I pretty sure I got the right types and that.
I have not have other problems with calling methods from session..

Comment: I am also stuck in the same situation. Did you find any solution here. Also, if you could please add your code for creating a OTSession. Thank you.

Comment: No did never find out about this.

Now sometimes I look at it last but pretty sure here I create a OTSession
http://www.codesend.com/view/51e2515eff2028c87f8130a67926345e/